# Prove that every integer greater than 1 is sum of square and squarefree.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, square-numbers, sieve-theory

I tried to put some sieve method on this. Here, we denote the classic squarefree sieve function $\sum_{d^2|a}\mu(d)$
(notice that if $a$ is squarefree, the value is 1, and if not squarefree, the value is 0, which is exactly what we want). 
I can take $A(n)=\lbrace n-1, n-4, n-9,...,n-[\sqrt n]^2\rbrace$ and take the sieve function to try to prove the following sum if positive.
$$\sum_{a\in A(n)}\sum_{d^2|a}\mu(d)$$
which is clearly the same value as following.
$$\sum_{1 \leq d \leq \sqrt{n-1}}\mu(d)A_{d^2}$$
Now all we have to do is calculate $A_{d^2}$ which is (with some calculation,)
$\left[\frac{[\sqrt n]}{d^2}\right]\prod_{p_{i}|d}\left(1+\left(\dfrac{n}{p_{i}}\right)\right) $
where $p_{i}$ denote primes and $()$ is legendre simble.
Now my question is, clearly if my conjecture is true, then above formula must sum up to a positive integer. However since I  lack so much on multiplicative number theory, I don't know what to do with the formula I have above. Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you allowing the use of zero as a square?

Comment: The way I calculated things, $A_{d^2}$ isn't exactly the value I wrote above, instead, they have error term of $O(\prod_{p_{i}|d}(1+\frac{1}{p_{i}}))$ so it wouldn't matter so much is my guess.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is important that $0$ be allowed as a square here; if not, $13$ cannot be expressed in the required form.

Comment: I guess so. But it doesnt matter much in sense of asymptotic formula like im trying to do.

Comment: I think you get an $O(\prod_{p\mid d}(1-(\tfrac np)))$ instead, and also an $O(1)$ if $n$ and $d$ are not coprime. It seems you'll have to bound the $O$'s explicitly.

Comment: In this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.03677.pdf they show that if $n\geq 10$ and $n\not \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $n$ is the sum of the square of a prime and a square-free number

Comment: That almost kills it. Thanks Robert Z. How about 1 (mod4)??

Comment: I don't understand your question. Let $f(n) = \sum_{d^2 | n} \mu(d) = |\mu(n)|$ (proof : use that $f$ is multiplicative). Thus $\sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt{n}} f(n-m^2)=\sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt{n}}|\mu(n-m^2)| \ge 0$. You also have $\sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt{n}} f(n-m^2) = \sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt{n}} \sum_{d^2 | n-m^2} \mu(d) = \sum_d \mu(d) B_d$ where $B_d= \sum_{m=1}^{\sqrt{n}} 1_{d^2 | n-m^2}$. The fact $B_d = \# E_d$ where $E_{d'} \subset E_d$ whenever $d| d'$ is enough to show $\sum_d \mu(d) B_d\ge 0$ by the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: If we consider a non-square number $ns$ and a square number $s$ we have for numbers >2:
$ns=ns+0$ and $s=(s-1) +1$ where $0$ is a square and $s-1$ is a non-square, so it seems trivial if 0 is allowed to be a square.

Comment: @MikaelJensen "non-square" and "square-free" mean different things. A number is non-square if it is not the square of an integer; a number is square-free if no square number divides it. For example, $12$ is non-square, but it is not squarefree as $2^2|12$.